# Как открыть окно?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день! У меня есть скрипт модального окна. На странице много таких окон, соответственно и ссылок на них. Во время открытия окна №1, при необходимости есть возможность открыть поверх него окно №2. Но только в том случае, если ссылка на окно №2 находится не в окне №1. Мне не получается сделать так, чтобы окно №2 я мог открыть не только со страницы, но и с окна №1. Прошу прощения за каламбур. Помогите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так? Благодарю!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.modal').on('click', function() {
        var $me = $(this);
        var id = $me.data("id");
        var topMenuHeight = 0;
        var $tab = $('.modal[data-id=' + id + ']');
        var $tabBody = $('.modal-content[data-id = ' + id + '-content]');

    $('.modal-content[data-id = ' + id + '-content]').animate({opacity: "show"}, 1000);

    $('.modal-close').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    $('.modal-content[data-id = ' + id + '-content]').fadeOut(500);
    }); 

    });
});
```

Comment: а в чем смысл `var $tab = $('.modal[data-id=' + id + ']');`? он разве вернет что-то кроме того, что уже в  `$me`?

Comment: а в чем проблема открыть второе окно из первого? добавляешь на первое кнопку с `.modal` и все должно работать

Comment: стоит добавить [mcve], код js стандартен и должен работать и так.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимо добавить строку: `$('.modal-content').hide();`